# How to parser XML exactly XLIFF files and get the *source* content in PHP

Tags: php, xml

How to parser XML exactly XLIFF files and get the source content in PHP.
how to get the source content of the xml file http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/cs02/Sample_AlmostEverything_1.2_strict.xlf

Comment: the file is http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/cs02/Sample_AlmostEverything_1.2_strict.xlf

how to get all the source content?

Answer (score 2):

In XQuery `//xliff` means any xliff element in the document. `/xliff` means from the root of the document. `./xliff` or or `xliff` gets children of the current node.

Comment: From root only.  Current node is '.'

Comment: Jim's right.  "./xliff" or "xliff" gets you children of the current node.

Comment: Edit your answer - if someone makes a comment, correct it, because not everyone that google reads the comments.

Answer (score 0):

//xliff finds all <xliff> tags at any depth of nesting within the document.  /xliff finds them (it) only at the root level.